# Why I get error in Redhat linux for CodeIgniter REST_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu-14.04, redhat

I have written a code in CodeIgniter and it is running on Ubuntu but when I try to run it in Redhat it gives me the error below :

syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/html/dgfp-v1/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php on line 32

Please help me.

Comment: Looks like you have an extra bracket at line 32. a copy of the code would be helpful.

Comment: I have not edited the REST_Controller.php library. And please note that that is working on Ubuntu but not on Redhat linux.

Comment: it might be related to the php-version on redhat.

Comment: As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mdamia, it should be something to do with PHP version. I have the same issue and after replacing the [] with array().
I've received another error Using PHP v5.3.24, though PHP v5.4 or greater is required
[Using PHP v5.3.24, though PHP v5.4 or greater is required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLAZi.png)

Here it is the REST_Controller.php i have updated.
[enter link description here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=66398506B8D4B8BF!795&authkey=!AHZ9p1CAgl0NmdA&ithint=file%2Cphp)

Hope this help